# Change AllowedRemoteHostUrl after the app is installed

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I use a SharePoint-hosted app to allow a 3rd party html site make REST calls into my SharePoint library using requestExecutor.js. That works fine in my test environment, but deployment to other environments is the problem. In order for teh cross site library to work on non-sharepoint pages (or of a 3rd party web site), I need to provide the url of that remote site in appManifest.xml:

```
<AppPrincipal>
  <Internal  AllowedRemoteHostUrl="http://3rdpartysite.com"/>
</AppPrincipal>
```

That site url is obviously different in dev/test/production. Also, there might be more than one remote site that I want to allow access to a library on my sharepoint. So I am trying to figure out how I can change `AllowedRemoteHostUrl` value for an already installed app instance. I don't see any powershell scripts nor I can find where thsi value is stored in the content database (I know making changes to content database is a big no-no, but if that worked I'd be willing to take the risk).

Any ideas? Or, what is the standard approach for such a task?

Comment: hope this link helps you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx

Comment: If it is an already installed app can't you simply update the .app file and then update the app instance on the site? Don't have any experience with **"AllowedRemoteHostUrl"** but if the app permissions can be updated this way, why not the urls?

Comment: Did you try updating the AppPrincipal from _layouts/15/AppInv.aspx? When you go to this page, just paste your client id and the updated AppPrincipal XML in the text boxes provided.

Comment: @Ciamas - how do I update the app instance?

Comment: @Andrey - like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179904.aspx#Minor You don't have to wait the time specified. You can also hover the mouse on the app tile in Site Contents, than click on these three dots which appear and afterwards "About". There you'll also be able to update the app instance.